# Bash Shell Script syntax Error finding product of squares

Tags: bash, shell

The task in question

> Task 2: Find all the numbers that can be written as the product of two even square numbers in
> succession and print them in increasing order. (For example, 64 is the first number that should be
> in your output as 4x16=64, where 4 and 16 are two even square numbers in succession). The user
> should specify how many such numbers they want to print. For each number found the program
> should also check/state whether the number found was odd or even and print this information
> too.

This is the function for said problem

```
function findProductOfSquares() {
    echo "Enter how many such numbers you want to find:"
    read limit

    echo "Numbers that are products of two consecutive even square numbers:"

    count=0
    for (( i = 2; count < limit; i += 2 )); do
        product=$(( i * i * (i + 2) * (i + 2) ))
        if [[ $product % 2 -eq 0 ]]; then
            parity="even"
        else
            parity="odd"
        fi
        echo "$product is $parity"
        count=$((count + 1))
    done
```

which comes back with

> conditional binary operator expected
> syntax error near '%'
> if [[$product % 2 -eq o]]; then'

Comment: Use an arithmetic context if you want to perform math.

Comment: `(( product % 2 == 0 ))` for example will work, as will `[[ $(( product % 2 )) -eq 0 ]]` (though the latter seems silly to me).

Comment: Since the product can only be a multiple of 4, I don't see the point of the parity test. Also, `count` can be incremented in the `for` statement, like in C: `for (( i = 2; count < limit; count++, i += 2 ))`

Comment: `%` is not a valid operator in a `[[ .... ]]` command. Have a look at the bash man page, section _Compound Commands_ , to see what operators are available.